# When I print out my list it prints out null for all my values..... How do I fix this issue???? I want to learn how to fix this issue for future

Tags: java, list, class

I made a list for my teachers and print out the list. The list prints, but the problem is that my list prints out null for all values in my list. It gives me null for first name, last name, id and course. What am I doing wrong??? How can I fix this? I want to be able to print out my actual values in my list of teachers. I don't see what could be the issue if I'm being totally honest. I add the first name, last name, id and course to the teacher list correctly. So, what am I missing?

Error:
[image]

Main.java code:

```
package SchoolSystem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int ch; //user choice
        teacher teachers = new teacher();
        student students = new student();
        //add teachers
        List<teacher> teach = new ArrayList<>();
        teach.add(new teacher(teachers.first_name, teachers.last_name, teachers.teacher_id, teachers.course));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        loop : while (true) {
            //menu
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1: Add Teacher"); //user can add a teachers name, id, and course
            System.out.println("2: Add Student"); //user can add a students name, id, courses, and GPA
            System.out.println("3: All Teachers"); //user can access teacher list and change items
            System.out.println("4: All students"); //user can access student list and change items
            System.out.println("5: Exit Program");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            ch = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
            switch (ch) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's first name: ");
                    teachers.first_name = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's last name: ");
                    teachers.last_name = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's id: ");
                    teachers.teacher_id = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's course: ");
                    teachers.course = sc.next();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter student's first name: ");
                    students.first_name = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter student's last name: ");
                    students.last_name = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter student's id: ");
                    students.student_id = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter student's course: ");
                    students.course = sc.next();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.printf("%1s %20s %5s %5s", "FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "ID", "COURSE");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    for(teacher teacher: teach){
                        System.out.format("%1s %20s %5s %5s",
                                teacher.getFirstName(), teacher.getLastName(), teacher.getId(), teacher.getCourse());
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    //null
                    break;

                case 5:
                    /*
                    System.out.println("Exiting Program....");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    break loop;
                     */
                    break;

                default:
                    //System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please enter an option (1 - 5)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Teacher.java code:

```
package SchoolSystem;

public class teacher {
    public teacher() {
        //null
    }

    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String teacher_id;
    public String course;

    public teacher(String first_name, String last_name, String teacher_id, String course) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.teacher_id = teacher_id;
        this.course = course;
    }

    //return firstname
    public String getFirstName() {
        return first_name;
    }

    //return lastname
    public String getLastName() {
        return last_name;
    }

    //return teacherId
    public String getId() {
        return teacher_id;
    }

    //return course
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you do is add a teacher using an uninitialized "teacher". Later you update that single instance of teacher; your next problem will be that all the teachers in the list have the same data.

Comment: Its supposed to be from the list "teach"

Comment: How can I fix this? Sorry I'm new to Java... I would appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Teacher Class  you must add setters

public class Teacher {

```
public Teacher() {
    //null
}

public String first_name;
public String last_name;
public String teacher_id;
public String course;

public Teacher(String first_name, String last_name, String teacher_id, String course) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.teacher_id = teacher_id;
    this.course = course;
}

//return firstname
public String getFirstName() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
   this.first_name = firstName;
}

//return lastname
public String getLastName() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.last_name = lastName;
 }

//return teacherId
public String getId() {
    return teacher_id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.teacher_id = id;
 }

//return course
public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course = course;
 }
```

}

in Main
delete this line

```
teach.add(new Teacher(teachers.getFirstName(), teacher.getLastName(), teacher.getId(), teacher.getCourse()));
```

and write:

```
int ch; //user choice
        
        //add teachers
        List<Teacher> teach = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //          teach.add(new Teacher(teachers.getFirstName(), teacher.getLastName(), teacher.getId(), teacher.getCourse()));

        loop : while (true) {
            //menu
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1: Add Teacher"); //user can add a teachers name, id, and course
            System.out.println("2: Add Student"); //user can add a students name, id, courses, and GPA
            System.out.println("3: All Teachers"); //user can access teacher list and change items
            System.out.println("4: All students"); //user can access student list and change items
            System.out.println("5: Exit Program");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            ch = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
            switch (ch) {
                case 1:
                    Teacher teachers = new Teacher();
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's first name: ");
                    teachers.setFirstName(sc.next());
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's last name: ");
                    teachers.setLastName(sc.next());
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's id: ");
                    teachers.setId(sc.next() );
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher's course: ");
                    teachers.setCourse (sc.next());

                    teach.add(teachers);
                    
                    break;

                case 2:
                // .....
```

use setters to add values and add "teachers" oject to List

```
teach.add(teachers);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that would be adding the same "teachers" object to the list, which wont work. And if the OP manages to get it to work, every time the "teachers" variable is updated, all the objects will have the same data. See my answer if I haven't explained it well here.

Comment: @computercarguy I just wanted to correct  this instruction " teach.add(new Teacher(teachers.getFirstName(), teacher.getLastName(), teacher.getId(), teacher.getCourse()));" Because it was a wrong order in writing the instructions I know very well that it should be written Teacher teachers = new Teacher();
 teach.add(teachers);

Comment: `Teacher teachers = new Teacher();` should be in the loop. With it still outside the loop, it's only a single instance that will be overwritten by every new teacher's data. The way you have it modified, it'll likely have a runtime error trying to add an object to a list it's already a member of.

Comment: I understand you well, It was just a small  mistake , I was concentrating on explaining to him the setters, thanks,

Comment: Setters and Getters aren't really necessary. The real problem was the location of the variable, how it was added to the list, and where it was added. I'm glad you fixed your answer. As you know, even that one misplaced line of code being out of place would still cause the OP problems.

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

You are having OOP issues with your code.

```java
teacher teachers = new teacher();
...
List<teacher> teach = new ArrayList<>();
teach.add(new teacher(teachers.first_name, teachers.last_name, teachers.teacher_id, teachers.course));
```

This snippet takes a new instance of a `teacher` and then creates a brand new instance of `teacher` to add to the list. *These are 2 distinct objects.* I'm assuming you are coming from C or C++ and you are thinking of them as pointers? Fortunately, that's not how Java works.

You can simply add the "teachers" variable to the "teach" list. Then when you later update the "teachers" object, the data will be available in the "teach" list.

The caveat to this is you need to instantiate a new object for "teachers" inside the loop, as well as moving the modified `teach.add(teachers);` into the loop.

```java
List<teacher> teach = new ArrayList<>();
List<student> stud = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

loop : while (true) {
    ...
    switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            teacher teachers = new teacher();
            ...
            teach.add(teachers);
            break;
        case 2:
            student students = new student();
            ...
            stud.Add(students);
            break;
        ...
```

Now you have a new `teacher` object for every teacher as well as a list containing only valid data, rather than empty objects.

This works because "teach" now contains a reference to the instance of "teachers". This is similar to the pointers of C and C++ I mentioned earlier. In this case, you have a reference to the whole object, not to the individual properties of the object you were trying to have earlier.

Think of an object as a piece of paper and a list as a box. You can put all kinds of data on the paper, then put the piece of paper in the box. When you need a new object, you get a new piece of paper, write the data on it, and add it to the box. Then when you want to update an object, you find it in the box and update the data. It's that simple. You can have a complex object where it has instances of other objects in it, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

### On a side note

Classes `teacher` and `student` should be capitalized as `Teacher` and `Student`. The list of `Teachers` should be named "teachers" and a single `Teacher` object should be named "teacher", or something that won't be confused with the class name. In general, lists should be plural and a singular instance should be singular.